# How can I integrate google tag manager system into my mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How can I integrate google tag manager system into my mvc project? I want to check if users' addblocks are open on my mvc project.Now I can detect if the user's addblock is turned on.

How can I do this system on google tag manager system?

```
 <script>
        let fakeAd = document.createElement("div");
        fakeAd.className =
            "textads banner-ads banner_ads ad-unit ad-zone ad-space adsbox"

        fakeAd.style.height = "1px"

        document.body.appendChild(fakeAd)

        let x_width = fakeAd.offsetHeight;
        let msg = document.getElementById("msg")


        if (x_width) {
            console.log("Addblock aktif değil .")

        } else {
            console.log("AdBlocker aktif");

            dataLayer = [{
                'key1': 'value1',
                'key2': 'value2'
            }];


            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', '*******');
            console.log("qq");


        }
    </script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do adblocker check in GTM because most of them block GTM itself. Theoretically, you could load GTM and then check if GTM is loaded from outside, but that would be extensive and not needed.

Implement your logic outside of GTM, or ask Front-end to help. Again, GTM is NOT the correct tool for this.